# Why can't I colour my segmented region from the original image

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I have the following code:

```
close all;
star = imread('/Users/name/Desktop/folder/pics/OnTheBeach.png');

blrtype = fspecial('average',[3 3]);
blurred = imfilter(star, blrtype);

[rows,cols,planes] = size(star);
R = star(:,:,1); G = star(:,:,2); B = star(:,:,3);
starS = zeros(rows,cols);
ind = find(R > 190 & R < 240 & G > 100 & G < 170 & B > 20 & B < 160);
starS(ind) = 1;

K = imfill(starS,'holes');

stats = regionprops(logical(K), 'Area', 'Solidity');
ind = ([stats.Area] > 250 & [stats.Solidity] > 0.1);
L = bwlabel(K);
result = ismember(L,find(ind));
```

Up to this point I load an image, blur to filter out some noise, do colour segmentation to find the specific objects which fall in that range, then create a binary image that has value `1` for the object's colour, and `0` for all other stuff. Finally I do region filtering to remove any clutter that was left in the image so I'm only left with the objects I'm looking for.

[image: object I was looking for in original image]

Now I want to recolour the original image based on the segmentation mask to change the colour of the starfish. I want to create Red,Green,Blue channels, assign value to them then lay the mask over the image. (To have red starfishes for example)

```
red = star;
red(starS) = starS(:,:,255);
green = star;
green(starS) = starS(:,:,0);
blue = star;
blue(starS) = star(:,:,0);
out = cat(3, red, green, blue);
imshow(out);
```

This gives me an error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Project4 (line 28)
red(starS) = starS(:,:,255);

What is wrong with my current approach?

Comment: Can you provide the original image too please?

Comment: [original picture](https://imgur.com/AG8w2po) @TommasoBelluzzo

Comment: `starS` is a 2D matrix. Why are you trying to access `starS(:,:,255)`?

Comment: Essential I to wanted to transform the mask ‘starS’ into a 3D matrix so I can lay it over the original image (they would be the same size then). Whilst setting its Red colour channel to maximum. I didn’t know how this could be done @CrisLuengo

Comment: You'd want to convert it to a 3D matrix, but the 3rd dimension should have size 3. `starS(:,:,1)` would be the red channel. `starS(:,:,255)` would the 255th channel... :)

Comment: Ah got it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is kinda confusing... I don't understand whether the mask you want to use is `starS` or `result` since both look like 2d indexers. In your second code snippet you used `starS`, but the mask you posted in your question is `result`.

Anyway, no matter what your desired mask is, all you have to do is to use the [imoverlay function](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imoverlay.html). Here is a small example based on your code:

```
out = imoverlay(star,result,[1 0 0]);
imshow(out);
```

and here is the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Just as a note, the newer labeloverlay function supports control of the transparency of the overlay: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/labeloverlay.html

Answer (score 0):

If the opaque mask of `imoverlay` suggested by Tommaso is not what you're after, you can modify the RGB values of the input to cast a hue over the selected pixels without saturating them. It is only slightly more involved.

```
I = find(result);
```

gives you an index of the pixels in the 2D image. However, `star` is 3D. Those indices will point at the same pixels, but only at the first 2D slice. That is, if `I` points at pixel `(x,y)`, it is equivalently pointing to pixel `(x,y,1)`. That is the red component of the pixel. To index `(x,y,2)` and `(x,y,2)`, the green and blue components, you need to increment `I` by `numel(result)` and `2*numel(result)`. That is, `star(I)` accesses the red component of the selected pixels, `star(I+numel(result))` accesses the green component, and `star(I+2*numel(result))` accesses the blue component.

Now that we can access these values, how do we modify their color?

This is what `imoverlay` does:

```
I = find(result);
out = star;
out(I) = 255; % red channel
I = I + numel(result);
out(I) = 0; % green channel
I = I + numel(result);
out(I) = 0; % blue channel
```

Instead, you can increase the brightness of the red proportionally, and decrease the green and blue. This will change the hue, increase saturation, and preserve the changes in intensity within the stars. I suggest the gamma function, because it will not cause strong saturation artefacts:

```
I = find(result);
out = double(star)/255;
out(I) = out(I).^0.5; % red channel
I = I + numel(result);
out(I) = out(I).^1.5; % green channel
I = I + numel(result);
out(I) = out(I).^1.5; % blue channel
imshow(out)
```

[image: output of code snippet]

By increasing the `1.5` and decreasing the `0.5` you can make the effect stronger.